# TFS Permission for work item

Tags: tfs

I use TFS 2012 and want to set following permission to group of TFS users.

1. Allow create new issue item.
2. Deny create new task item.
3. Deny change his task item and can only change remind time, description and state of it. and cant change assigned user, priority and iteration of it.

can I set this permission.

**Edit**

in the area configuration exist following access:

1. Create Child nodes
2. Delete this node
3. Edit this node
4. Edit work items in this node
5. Manage test plans
6. View permissions for this node
7. View work items in this node

and in the iteration configuration exists following access :

1. Create child nodes
2. Delete this node
3. Edit this node
4. View permission for this node

Can I add my requested access to area and iteration security configuration.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practise is to affect to yours members `Contributor group`, with this group permissions permit to work on project without administrator role.
You can set permission in `security section` on `Web Portal`

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252467(v=vs.80).aspx